# Recreation of apt based source download

Tags: apt, source

Source for a apt package can be obtained with the command:

```
apt-get source foo
```

This produces a directory with four entries in it: a directory of source and three files, foo*****.dsc, foo*****.tar.gz and foo*****.diff.gz.

Assume that the directory of source is corrupted, can these files be used to recreate it? ( As I assume it can. )

How?

Answer (score 1):

To re-create the source directory, delete it and run

```
dpkg-source -x foo...dsc
```

This will extract everything using the `.dsc` and the two tarballs (or the tarball and patch as in your example).

Comment: Which is a thin wrapper around extracting the tar and applying the diff, which can be done manually if necessary.

Comment: Indeed, for old-style packages with a `.diff.gz`. But other packages can be more complex to extract manually (take a look at `libreoffice` for example), and `dpkg-source` handles any Debian source package you can find.